# Separate page won't load if query is running

Tags: php

I have a large internal PHP application and just noticed that if a database query is being executed in one tab (via form post) then I can't get any page to load on another tab until the query finishes.

We noticed that if we open an incognito window then things load fine, which leads us to believe this is an issue with session management. We are currently using Google OAuth2 in conjunction with $_SESSION to hold access tokens and wrapping that around our template engine (so that only verified users registered with our Google domain can access our application) but I don't see how that could cause this issue as all it does is read from $_SESSION, interact with Google_Client, and execute a callback based on success or failure.

Anybody experienced this, or have any advice on how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Potentially your app relies on a something in the database being available, but your query on POST is locking the table. Beyond that, I'm not sure what we can say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second request may be waiting for the php session to be released by the first one. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: Yes, I was doing session_start() at the beginning of each script. Changed process to session_start(), authenticate session, session_write_close(), execute callback, just within my SessionManager class, removing session_start() from everywhere else. Exactly what was wrong.